# DateTime ParseExact conversion increasing month by 1

Tags: c#, datetime

Trying to use ParseExact to convert a string to datetime but the resulted datetime seems to be increasing the month by 1. What am I missing

```
DateTime.ParseExact("7/22/2015 8:08:01 PM", "m/d/yyyy h:M:s tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Result: `22-08-2015 20:07:01`

Comment: `m` is minute, `M` is month.

Comment: ^^ add that as an answer @Corak

Comment: Ok So the problem was that m is taking a minute but can you also tell me the exact format to use to get it converted?

Comment: Also I would use `mm` and `ss` specifiers in minute and second parts for _consistency_ since their single digit values have leading zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lol, change it to :

```
var d = DateTime.ParseExact("7/22/2015 8:08:01 PM", "M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 5):

You mixed up `m` and `M` for minutes and months. So it's just coincidence it looks like the month is increased by 1.

The correct code would be:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("7/22/2015 8:08:01 PM", "M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 3):

m is minute, M is month.
The code is not increasing the month by one but picking out the 08 minute part of the input.  You want

```
"M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt"
```